# SonarQube not able to record the coverage

Tags: c#, tfs, sonarqube, azure-devops

I am using SonarQube 6.7 and TFS Plugin Sonar version 4.0. 
Before the upgrade from of both the server and plugin I am able to get the coverage but now not no coverage is recorded from the MSTest. The same code with coverage is recorded when used with dot cover. 
Sonar is able to record the number of tests and the coverage in TFS Build is also recorded yet it doesn't work. I have checked for the trx and the coverage files as well which is available but only *.coverage file is available not the coveragexml file. Is there any solution for this.
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you installed C# plugin, what's the detail version of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be the same issue as this one-- **[Code Coverage report is no longer imported](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-csharp/issues/492)**

Try to use the workaround provided by *Evangelink* :

> It seems like we have a regression on the Scanner for MSBuild (ticket:
>   https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARMSBRU-339).
>
> While this ticket is being addressed you can fix this issue by simply
>   adding `/d:sonar.cs.vscoveragexml.reportsPaths="**\*.coveragexml"`
>   into the Additional Settings of the SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild -
>   Begin Analysis (new) task.

Just as you analyzed, with this command the `.coveragexml` will generated correctly and able to record the coverage.

Comment: I have detected that the coveragexml file is not generated and seems like we need to have codecoverage.exe to generate it. Can I get codecoverage.exe as part of Build tools? Right now im running with Visual Studio Professional on the Build Agent server.

Comment: what do you recommend using visual studio or build tools in the Agent server?